# What .byte start_of_setup-1f means in linux kernel code

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel

I want understand the meaning of x86 real mode entry point in linux kernel:

```
_start:
        # Explicitly enter this as bytes, or the assembler
        # tries to generate a 3-byte jump here, which causes
        # everything else to push off to the wrong offset.
        .byte   0xeb        # short (2-byte) jump
        .byte   start_of_setup-1f
```

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/boot/header.S#n298

Specifically the last line `.byte start_of_setup-1f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1:` is a [local label](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#index-local-labels-217).

`1f` is a reference to label `1` Forward of the current line.  (A file can contain multiple numeric labels.  This is mostly useful for inline-asm or assembler macros which can insert the same block of code in multiple locations.)

So

```
.byte   start_of_setup - 1f
```

is the distance (in bytes) between the two labels, truncated (if necessary) down to one byte.

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more links to docs and guides.